# Walter Rudin Real and Complex Analysis Chapter 2

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Walter Rudin Real and Complex Analysis Chapter 2 2.14 Riesz representation theorem the last step.

Why did he put the absolute value of $a$ ?

Is not it sufficient to assume $f$ is positive?

> **Proof.**
>   Clearly, it is enough to prove this for real $f$.
>   Also, it is enough to prove the *inequality*
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{16}
>        \Lambda f
>   \leq \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
> \end{equation}
>   for every real $f \in C_c(X)$.
>   For once $(16)$ is established, the linearity of $\Lambda$ shows that
>   $$
>        -\Lambda f
>   =    \Lambda(-f)
>   \leq \int_X (-f) \,\mathrm{d}\mu
>   =    - \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu,
> $$
>   which, together with $(16)$ shows that equality holds in $(16)$.
>
> Let $K$ be the support of the real $f \in C_c(X)$, let $[a,b]$ be an interval which contains the range of $f$ (note the Corollary to Theorem 2.10), choose $\epsilon > 0$, and choose $y_i$, for $i = 0, 1, \dotsc, n$, so that $y_i - y_{i-1} < \epsilon$ and
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{17}
>   y_0 < a < y_1 < \dotsb < y_n = b.
> \end{equation}
>   Put
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{18}
>     E_i
>   = \{ x : y_{i-1} < f(x) \leq y_i \} \cap K
>   \qquad
>   (i = 1, \dotsc, n)
> \end{equation}
>   Since $f$ is continuous, $f$ is Borel measurable, and the sets $E_i$ are therefore disjoint Borel sets whose union is $K$.
>   There are open sets $V_i \supset E_i$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
>   \tag{19}
>     \mu(V_i)
>   < \mu(E_i) + \frac{\epsilon}{n}
>   \qquad
>   (i = 1, \dotsc, n)
> \end{equation}
>   and such that $f(x) < y_i + \epsilon$ for all $x \in V_i$.
>   By Theorem 2.13, there are functions $h_i \prec V_i$ such that $\sum h_i = 1$ on $K$.
>   Hence $f = \sum h_i f$, and Step II shows that
>   $$
>        \mu(K)
>   \leq \Lambda\left( \sum h_i \right)
>   =    \sum \Lambda h_i.
> $$
>   Since $h_i f \leq (y_i + \epsilon) h_i$, and since $y_i - \epsilon < f(x)$ on $E_i$, we have
>   \begin{align*}
>         \Lambda f
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda(h_i f)
>    \leq \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i + \epsilon) \Lambda h_i \\
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \Lambda h_i
>         - |a| \sum_{i=1}^n \Lambda h_i \\
>   &\leq \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon)[ \mu(E_i) + \epsilon/n ]
>         - |a| \mu(K) \\
>   &=    \sum_{i=1}^n (y _i - \epsilon) \mu(E_i)
>         + 2 \epsilon \mu(K)
>         + \frac{\epsilon}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (|a| + y_i + \epsilon) \\
>   &\leq \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu
>         + \epsilon[ 2\mu(K) + |a| + b + \epsilon ].
> \end{align*}
>
> (Original scanned image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BYQA.png)).)

Comment: Since every real function $f$ can be written $f=f^+ - f^-$ both of them are positive

Comment: To avoid putting the absolute value $a$

Comment: Why can't I apply what I said to this proof ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use $a$ instead of $|a|$ you cannot go from the second to the third line, since not knowing that sign of $a$ precludes you from knowing if you keep the inequality $\sum_i\Lambda_i\geq\mu(K)$.

And, if you  do the proof just for $f\geq0$, you only get the inequality $\Lambda f\leq\int_Xf\,d\mu$, and not equality.

Comment: Thanks Merci Danke